# HP 8300 CMT – short circuit with case

Tags: boot, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply, case

I have an HP 8300 CMT with the following specs:

- i5 3570
- 8 GB RAM
- GTX 1060
- 600W EVGA PSU

I had some issues that were related to the fans spinning up for a second and then nothing happens. Sometimes it would eventually boot up but it was very unreliable.

I think I have managed to pinpoint the problem: When the motherboard is removed from the case and just on a sheet of plastic, everything boots up just fine (the dedicated GPU is not recognized, but I have only tried once or twice with the GTX connected).

I initially thought that I put in the screws too tightly and so some conductive parts of the MoBo would touch the metal plate of the case, but it still shows the same issues with loose screws. I have tried to gradually add screws too but that led to very inconsistent results (boots sometimes, often not).

The proprietary case however does not have standoffs – it has some raised metal parts where you can screw in your motherboard and that's it.

Is there a standard procedure for these issues that I can try or can you help me out?

Comment: You could buy a bag of standoffs on eBay for pence.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend investing in something like this https://www.amazon.co.uk/Pingranso-Personal-Computer-Standoffs-Motherboard-300-Pcs-Screw-Kit/dp/B07FXJBHSW/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1553156777&sr=8-1&keywords=motherboard+screw+set, and be sure to use the nylon insulation discs (the red flat circles)

Comment: Thank for your comment!
Is insulation really wanted - I thought the motherboards needs a connection to ground? I rather had the impression that some unwanted touches (besides the screws) may have created this short circuit.

Please correct me if I am wrong - I am far from an expert on this field.

Comment: Your PSU has a 8 ground pins, i wouldn't worry about that.